# Trying to assign BeautifulSoup output to variable to get text from it

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pipe the results from a find_all function to another find_all function, then extract the text from that result set so I can enter that into either a data frame or a text file. I keep running into a headache because I can get most of it done but am missing the last piece of the puzzle.

Here is the HTML code I'm trying to extract the text from:

```
<div class="card-headers"><a href="/reviews/market/data-preparation-tools/vendor/microsoft/product/microsoft-power-bi" class="card-top-header " data-interaction="Select Vendor" data-catchpoint-elem="card-title" data-vendor-name="Microsoft - Product name">Microsoft Power BI</a><div class="card-sub-header">by Microsoft</div></div>
```

Here is the code I have which works, but won't allow me to extract the product name: Microsoft Power BI.

```
pList = rec_list.find_all(class_="card-headers")
resultA = []
for pl in pList: resultA.extend(pl.find_all(class_="card-top-header"))
```

If I go simple with this code:

```
program = rec_list.find_all(class_="card-top-header")
```

I get everything duplicated because the class is repeated in two separate divs with different classes.

I'm likely missing the obvious here. Thank you in advance for any assistance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to accomplish?
`product_names = [a.text for a in rec_list.select("div.card-headers > a")]`

Comment: That brought me back more than I needed.

Comment: ```'Company Size',
 'Industry',
 'Region',
 "Customers' Choice 2020",
 '',
 'Microsoft Power BI',
 '645 Ratings',
 '',
 'Microsoft Power BI',
 'Read reviews\r',
 'Microsoft vs Tableau',
 'Microsoft vs Qlik',
 'Microsoft vs IBM',
 'See All Alternatives\r',
 "Customers' Choice 2020",```

Comment: Edited. If a larger sample of the html is provided it will be easier to solve

Comment: I ended up getting it to work from the solution you provided. Thank you for your help!!